# How can I kill all running processes/softwares using terminal

Tags: terminal, process, kill

I want to kill all running softwares using my terminal. I already tried with killall but it requries the name of the software to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

Use `killall5 -9`

> killall5 is the SystemV killall command. It sends a signal
>   to all processes except kernel threads and the processes in its own
>   session, so it won't kill the shell that is running the script it was
>   called from. Its primary (only) use is in the rc scripts found in the
>   /etc/init.d directory.

You can find more information here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/killall5